# VB.NET 2008, XP, DateTime types

Tags: vb.net

I make a program on Windows7 with VB.NET 2008 which uses dates and datetime pickers which work's good.

Like this:

```
    With dtp_date1

        'here crashes
        .Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy.") & " 00:00:00"

        .Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        .CustomFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy. HH:mm:ss tt"
        .ShowUpDown = False
    End With

    With dtp_date2
        .Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy.") & " 23:59:59.9999"
        .Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        .CustomFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy. HH:mm:ss tt"
        .ShowUpDown = False
    End With
```

This works OK untill I put this program to windows XP.
Error appears:

> ```
> string was not recognized as a valid Datetime
> ```

I try to fix this so:

```
.Text = CDate(DateTimeNow.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy.") & " 00:00:00").ToString
```

And here get error:

> Conversion from string "06.01.2013. 00.00.00" to type 'Date' is not valid.

Since I have many places in program with dates what to do to fix this error?

Comment: You only want to set `dtp_date2` using date values in a `string` right?

Comment: You need to check the default _culture_ of the XP box. It is probably different to the ones in the other machines.

Comment: bonCodigo, I want to set dtp_date1 and dtp_date2 and more allaround a program. Oded, where I should change "culture" on XP or in win7? How to do that? Can I force certain "culture" for just my program?

Comment: When you first load the application you can set the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` to whatever culture you need.

Comment: Those are "hr-HR" and "en-US" on both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Never** assign the DateTimePicker.Text property.  You'll get slammed if the format of your string doesn't match the culture or the Control Panel overrides for the date/time format.

Always use the DateTimePicker.Value property.  A property of type DateTime, immune to format problems.  Fix:

```
    Dim now = DateTime.Now.Date
    dtp_date1.Value = now
    dtp_date2.Value = now.AddDays(1) - new TimeSpan(1)
```

Comment: Thank you Hans. I try and on win7 works again but nor on XP. I have to make Date from string "01.01.2013. 00:00:00" and "31.12.2013. 23:59:59.9999". How to do this porperly that datetimepicker and XP accept this as date?

Comment: Why are you still messing with strings?  I was pretty explicit about **not using strings**.  Use the Value property instead, like I showed in the snippet.

Comment: Actually, your example work's well (on XP too) with "today". I messing with strings because in program I have need for getting time "yesterday", "this week", "last week", "this month", "last month", "actual year" and all with start date+time 00:00:00 to end date and time 23:59:59.9999. Of course, for now I have all of this programmed as strings and workable on win7.

Comment: Those are all dates that you can get out of DateTime without using strings.